Analyzing ACE twin models from a long data set rather than wide data set
I am wondering if we can analyze ACE twin models from a long data set rather than the usual wide data set (R lavaan, mplus).
For example, I have found that you can create ACE twin data in R from here.
library(lavaan)
library(MASS)

A <- matrix(1,2,2) # genetic correlation for MZ's = 1
    C <- matrix(1,2,2)
E <- diag(2)
Adz <- matrix(c(1,.5,.5,1),2,2) # genetic correlation for DZ's = 0.5

# make 5 pairs of MZ twins 
MZ <- MASS::mvrnorm(5,mu=c(0,0),Sigma = A+C+E)

# Add a column to label as MZ:
MZ<- cbind.data.frame("MZ",MZ)
colnames(MZ) <- c("zyg","P1", "P2") 

# make 6 DZ twin pairs
DZ <- MASS::mvrnorm(6,mu=c(0,0),Sigma = Adz+C+E)

# add variable too label as DZ:
DZ <- cbind.data.frame("DZ",DZ)
colnames(DZ) <- c("zyg","P1", "P2")

# Combine MZ and DZ twins
dataset <- rbind(MZ,DZ)

which looks like this (kind of twins, score for twin 1 P1 and twin P2 from 11 families) :
dataset

   zyg          P1         P2
1   MZ  0.77171255 -1.2686729
2   MZ  0.38038471  0.9908333
3   MZ  0.62147499  1.4215385
4   MZ -1.88684235 -1.2684852
5   MZ  2.43757587  2.5915099
6   DZ -0.08042972  0.3650863
7   DZ -0.58447878 -1.6588859
8   DZ -1.59459223  0.5592639
9   DZ  0.94105014 -1.4935118
10  DZ -3.45143197 -3.6395244
11  DZ -0.68945343  1.6007301

The data set can be analysed through this model in lavaan,
ace.model<-"
A1=~ NA*P1 + c(a,a)*P1 
A2=~ NA*P2 + c(a,a)*P2 
C1 =~ NA*P1 + c(c,c)*P1
C2 =~ NA*P2 + c(c,c)*P2
# variances
A1 ~~ 1*A1
A2 ~~ 1*A2
C1 ~~ 1*C1
C2 ~~ 1*C2 
P1~~c(e2,e2)*P1 
P2~~c(e2,e2)*P2
# covariances
A1 ~~ c(1,.5)*A2 
A1 ~~ 0*C1 + 0*C2 
A2 ~~ 0*C1 + 0*C2 
C1 ~~ c(1,1)*C2
"
ace.fit <- lavaan::cfa(ace.model, data = dataset,group = "zyg")
summary(ace.fit)

Would it be possible to analyse this same model from a long data set instead of wide.
new.dateset <- tidyr::pivot_longer(dataset,
                                   cols = c("P1","P2"),
                                   values_to = "P")

I would also like to find how to generate data linearly like $P = A+C+E$ rather than from the covariance matrices if it is possible.

It makes your code more reproducible if you add the library statements - otherwise someone who copies your code will find it doesn't run, and won't necessarily know why. (It also helps if you qualify your function names, e.g. lavaan::cfa() - that way someone can see what package is missing.

I missed them. Thank you.

I've been thinking about this, but I haven't worked it out. One thing that might help is to make your sample bigger. Also, you can make the data long with tidyr::pivot_longer() which then doesn't require you to put the sample size. (I'll make the change if I remember.)
